# couchDB - how to display more than key/value?

Tags: jquery, json, couchdb, cloudant, nosql

I'm utterly stuck in my RDBMS ways of thinking and having one heck of a time going through limited tutorials and guides to get my head around noSQL

I created a database `bookmarks` in cloudant and created two documents like this:

```
{
  "_id": "3d609bd2689639afc2520f17d8f4c883",
  "_rev": "2-7227c3e1350f2d4f67f62f830b3f331e",
  "title": "bing homepage",
  "url ": "http://www.bing.com",
  "tags": [
    "search",
    "public"
  ],
  "dateadded": [
    2015,
    5,
    6
  ]
}

{
  "_id": "79cd702a5e23b80f09664862b5cbb918",
  "_rev": "1-f4428cbc76b31ec93a2b438cb6de6bb8",
  "title": "google homepage",
  "url ": "http://www.google.com",
  "tags": [
    "search",
    "private"
  ],
  "dateadded": [
    2015,
    5,
    7
  ]
}
```

Then I created a view document like this:

```
function (doc) {
      emit(doc.title, doc.url, doc.tags);
}
```

I expected to get a result with the three attributes I specified in the map function, but instead I get this:

```
{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[
   {"id":"3d609bd2689639afc2520f17d8f4c883","key":"bing homepage","value":null},
   {"id":"79cd702a5e23b80f09664862b5cbb918","key":"google homepage","value":null}
]}
```

I have two problems:

1. Why would my value be null? I removed the `doc.tags` thinking maybe I can only specify a key and value, but even then it still returns `doc.url` as `value:null`
2. How do I get my objects in the result array to contain the same attributes I was emitting in the map function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** you have a space after your "url **->** ". Remove it and it will work.

**2.** `emit` accepts only 2 parameters but you can do something like:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.title, [doc.url, doc.tags]);
}
```

Or even better:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.title, {"url": doc.url, "tags": doc.tags});
}
```

The first view will give you:

```
{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[
  {"id":"86d091d6ac800d27a6fb388a0900113d","key":"bing homepage","value":["http://www.bing.com",["search","public"]]},
  {"id":"86d091d6ac800d27a6fb388a09001692","key":"google homepage","value":["http://www.google.com",["search","private"]]}
]}
```

The second:

```
{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[
  {"id":"86d091d6ac800d27a6fb388a0900113d","key":"bing homepage","value":{"url":"http://www.bing.com","tags":["search","public"]}},
  {"id":"86d091d6ac800d27a6fb388a09001692","key":"google homepage","value":{"url":"http://www.google.com","tags":["search","private"]}}
]}
```